# Reduce size of ProgressDialog with ProgressBar

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I build following ProgressDialog by code:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("test..");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.setMax(50);
        progressDialog.show();
```

My app is running in landscape so this ProgressDialog is shown much to big in width. Jow can I reduce the width?

thx & regards